# Is there a simple way to uniformly get the path to 64-bit System32?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have BAT scripts that I sometimes run on my own computer from 64-bit cmd.exe, and also it has to work correctly on a build server that is a 32-bit process. The problem is that the script needs to reference the 64-bit folder `C:\Windows\System32`. And the 32-bit process maps it to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead.

There is the virtual [Sysnative folder](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm), but it doesn't exist for 64-bit processes (that would have been too easy).

Is there any way to solve this other than `if exist "%systemroot%\Sysnative" (...) else (...)` ?

P. S. All the hosts are 64-bit systems, there is no need to consider the possibility of a 32-bit Windows installation.

P. S. #2: `if exist "%systemroot%\Sysnative"` always takes the false branch, even though `dir "%systemroot%\Sysnative"` and similar commands work as expected. Awesome job, Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you always want to get System32 regardless of the process.

You can just use `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Edit: As you mentioned there is a transparent redirection in place and I don't think there is a way to bypass it in a batch file.

If you were writing a native application it could be done with [wow64disablewow64fsredirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection).

Regardless in this case it would be easiest to write the if statement.

Edit 2: `if exist` expects a trailing slash for directories. It works if you use `if exist "%systemroot%\Sysnative\" ...`

Comment: I think you did understand my question correctly, but no, that doesn't work! If you run the 32-bit version of cmd.exe, you will find that the path `C:\Windows\System32` actually points to the `SysWOW64` folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the trailing slash is important!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find out in the batch file whether it is running in
32-bit or 64-bit mode, you can test the value of the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
environment variable:

64-bit process architecture:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
```

32-bit process architecture:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
```

Note that if you wish to test a 32-bit CMD in a 64-bit Windows,
run `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any way to solve this other than*
> *`if exist "%systemroot%\Sysnative" (...) else (...)` ?*
> ...
> *Is there a simple way to uniformly get the path to 64-bit System32?*
>
> Try:
>
> Result in **Window 32**:
>
> ```cmd
>     echo;"%ComSpec:SysWOW64=System32%"         //   "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
>     echo;"%ComSpec:SysWOW64\cmd.exe=System32%" //   "C:\Windows\System32"
>     echo;"%__AppDir__:SysWOW64=System32%"      //   "C:\Windows\System32\"
> ```
>
> Result in **Window 64**:
>
> ```cmd
>     echo;"%ComSpec:SysWOW64=System32%"         // "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
>     echo;"%ComSpec:SysWOW64\cmd.exe=System32%" // "C:\Windows\System32"
>     echo;"%__AppDir__:SysWOW64=System32%"      // "C:\Windows\System32\"
> ```

---

**Obs.:** I also don't understand if the goal is always to run applications in 64-bit mode on 64-bit systems, or if it would be running in 32-bit even on 64-bit systems...

---

```cmd
@echo off

echo\ %__AppDir__% | find "SysWOW64" 1>nul || ( 
     start "" /b "%ComSpec:System32=SysWOW64%" /k "%~f0" 
     type "%temp%\test.txt" 
     exit /b
    )

echo\ %__AppDir__% >"%temp%\test.txt"

rem Your Commands
rem Your Commands
rem Your Commands
```

Result in file `"%temp%\test.txt"`:

```cmd
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
```

---

```cmd
@echo off

for %%i in (msvcp140,msvcp140_1,vcruntime140,vcruntime140_1)do 1>nul 2>nul =;(
    "%ComSpec:System32=SysWOW64%" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "%__AppDir__:System32\=SysWOW64%\%%~i.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
    );= || goto :dll_not_found

exit /b

:dll_not_found
echo\here im :dll_not_found
```

---

Commands result:

```cmd
 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140_1.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140_1.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
```

---

```cmd
@echo off

for %%i in (msvcp140,msvcp140_1,vcruntime140,vcruntime140_1)do 1>nul 2>nul =;(
     "%ComSpec:SysWOW64=System32%" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "%__AppDir__:SysWOW64\=System32%\%%~i.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
    );= || goto :dll_not_found

exit /b

:dll_not_found
echo\here im :dll_not_found
```

---

Commands result:

```cmd
 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\System32\\msvcp140.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\System32\\msvcp140_1.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\System32\\vcruntime140.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
 "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /v /c "xcopy /R /Y "C:\Windows\System32\\vcruntime140_1.dll" .\binaries\32\msvcr\"
```

---

- [`ComSpec%` **The COMSPEC variable**](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/command.php#Comspec)
- [`ComSpec%` **Comspec is used whenever the command shell spawns a new process**](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/command.php#Comspec)
- [`%__AppDir__%` **The directory path to the current application .exe**,

  terminated with a trailing backslash. (Global)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - [discuss](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?t=338)

---